# Looping through table records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a table as such:

[image: Screenshot of table]

Each record in the column `ColumnName` contains the name of a column in another table, `regressionDifferences`. I want to loop through `ColumnName` and select each of the columns in `regressionDifferences` and insert them into `ColumnContent`. At the moment I'm just focusing on printing the column content to the screen, and then I will worry about inserting it.
This is what I have written so far:

```
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = 1, @MaxRowNumber INT = 42762,
@ColumnName VARCHAR(max), @UniqueID VARCHAR(max)

WHILE(@LoopCounter < @MaxRowNumber)

BEGIN

SELECT @ColumnName = ColumnName
FROM ColumnDifference WHERE RowNumber = @LoopCounter

SELECT @UniqueID = UniqueID
FROM ColumnDifference WHERE RowNumber = @LoopCounter

SELECT DISTINCT @ColumnName AS ColumnContent FROM regressionDifferences rD
WHERE rD.UniqueID LIKE @UniqueID + '%'

SET @LoopCounter = @LoopCounter + 1

END
```

For some reason this is just returning the names of the columns, ie `a_4, a_4, a_4, a_10, a_11, a_6`, etc as opposed to the actual content of each column.

Can anyone help me as to where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @sql varchar(max);
set @sql ='SELECT DISTINCT ' + @ColumnName + 'AS ColumnContent FROM regressionDifferences rD WHERE rD.UniqueID LIKE ''' 
                       + @UniqueID + '%'''
exec(@sql);
```

use the above query to create dynamic sql you need.

your dynamic query is equivalent to

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'a_4' AS ColumnContent FROM regressionDifferences rD
WHERE rD.UniqueID LIKE '2016-07-26''+ '%'
```

The variable  `@ColumnName` is not treated as column name in your dynamic query. It is treated as text

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT @ColumnName AS ColumnContent FROM regressionDifferences rD
WHERE rD.UniqueID LIKE @UniqueID + '%'
```

Shouldn't @ColumnName have to be something else?

Comment: Why do you say that? I'm new to dynamic SQL but I think that's right, I've set @ColumnName to each record in the ColumnName column as it loops through it, and that's what I want to select from the other table. I could be wrong!

Comment: Your are selecting ColumnName twice, meaning that the result of your first query is overwritten by your third query. I suggest your create a ColumnName2 and use that in your third query. I hope i understand your question right.

Comment: You shouldn't asking questions through answers. Especially if you're not sure what the OP asks. In that case you just ignore the question, and move to another that you could understand and hopefully answer. Repeat this so you gather enough rep to leave comments. In comments you can ask for clarifications as much as you like...